# Как сделать чтобы фрейм таблицы изменялся в зависимости от количества элементов

Tags: ios, swift

Мне нужно чтобы автоматически менялась высота таблицы, чтобы пустых ячеек не было, `myTableView.frame.height`.
К примеру `arr.count = 1` высота таблицы сузилась до минимума и юзер видит только одну заполненную ячейку, если `arr.count = 4` то высота таблицы расширилась и юзер видит 4 заполненные ячейки, именно 4, а не к примеру 6 ячеек из которых 4 заполненны а остальные 2 пустые. Можно ли сделать это с помощью `autolayaut`? как это автоматизировать? Сверху вьюхи есть `Label` и снизу вьюхи есть `Label`, соответственно надо чтобы нижний `Label` "бегал" за таблицей то вверх, то вниз.

[image: Версия с 4 элементами]

Версия с одним элементом в т-це, высота т-цы не изменилась поэтому все что ниже осталось на своих местах, нужно чтобы все поднялось. 
[image: Версия с одним элементом]

Comment: Как вариант, вы можете просто прятать пустые ячейки. tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

Comment: @VitaliEller ваш вариант не подходит потому что пустые ячейки просто скрылись но высота таблицы осталось такой же, а мне надо чтобы высота таблицы сузилась.

Comment: Остальной контент будет подтягиваться вверх или только надпись должна?

Comment: @VAndrJ Остальной контент должен подтягиваться вверх.

Comment: Почему тогда все это не сделать одной tableView с разными ячейками, где "Статьи", "Фото" и другое - это заголовки секций?

Comment: @VAndrJ я не расписал все подробно, но под фото будет Collection View c горизонтальной прокруткой тоже самое будет и с видео.

Comment: Это не мешает сделать одной UITableView.

Comment: @VAndrJ в принципе можно попробовать, как я понял в массив вручную добавлять значение по последнему индексу, а в этом  значении у меня и будет collection view правильно ?

Comment: Если Вы используете autolayout, то укажите для констрейнт между низом таблицы как равно и высоту динамично (>= или <=) в зависимости от требований

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за интересные ответы, даже не думал что будет так много вариаций, использовал на мой взгляд самый просто вариант.

у `TableView` сделал constraint `height`

затем в коде создал метод

```
func setHeight() {
    heightConstrainForTV.constant = myTableView.contentSize.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

и вызываю его в

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    setHeight()
}
```

так же его вызываю метод `setHeight()` перед `myTableView.reloadData()`

Еще раз всем спасибо.